# In python 2.7, is it possible to capture the smtp client server dialogue when using smtplib? If so, how?

Tags: python-2.7, smtplib

I am using smtplib.sendmail() and would like to log or capture the smtp client-server dialogue information.

Comment: Probably not, but you can capture the client-server dialogue by logging tcp proxy on port 25.

Comment: Are things still not working for you? Any details so I could improve my answer to make it do work (again)?

Comment: No. All good now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [smtplib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/smtplib.html#smtp-objects):

```
SMTP.set_debuglevel(level)
```

> Set the debug output level. A true value for level results in debug messages for connection and for all messages sent to and received from the server

The example at the bottom of the page linked to above uses that:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('localhost')
server.set_debuglevel(1)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

Examining the library itself shows you should probably use an integer value that is greater than zero and not `True` as the description indicates, although `True` will work (as if you supplied `1`).